# Remove li from a dynamic list using blade and Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.5

I have a dynamically populated list. On clicking on the Approve/reject button, an AJAX call happens. If the response is 1, the `li` should be hidden from the UI.

Below is my code. The remove() option doesn't seem to work. Can't figure out a way.

**Approve.blade.php**

```
<ul>
   @foreach($pendlist as $pend)             
   <li id="{{$pend->id}}">
      <div class="list-box-listing">
         <div class="list-box-listing-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/listing-item-01.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
         <div class="list-box-listing-content">
            <div class="inner">
               <h3><a href="#">{{$pend->title}}</a></h3>
               <span>{{$pend->address}}, {{$pend->locality}}, {{$pend->city}}</span>
               <div class="star-rating" data-rating="3.5">
                  <div class="rating-counter">(12 reviews)</div>
                  <input type="hidden" value="{{$pend->id}}" id="propid">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons-to-right">
         <a href="#" class="button gray reject" id="reject"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Reject</a>
         <a href="#" class="button gray approve" id="approve"><i class="sl sl-icon-check"></i> Approve</a>
      </div>
   </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#approve').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url('/api/approve') }}",
        async: true,
        data: {
          id: $('#propid').val(),
          status: 1
        },
        success: function(result) {
          let id = $('#propid').val();
          if (result == 1) {
            $(this).remove();
          }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(errorThrown);
          $("#loader").hide();
        }
      });
```

I have tried:

```
$(this).closest('li').remove()
```

But that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You want to remove anchor `approve` or `li` ??

Comment: i want to remove the `li`

Comment: Try `$('#approve').click(function(){ var that = $(this); ...` and inside the succes handler `that.closest('li').remove();`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parent` with`closest` . Hold your scope of  `this` on variable.

```js
$('.approve').click(function() {
  let $this = this;
  //Your ajex call
  $($this).parent().closest('li').remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box-listing">
      other stuff
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-to-right">
      <a href="#" class="button gray reject" id="{{$pend->id}}"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Reject</a>
      <a href="#" class="button gray approve" id="{{$pend->id}}"><i class="sl sl-icon-check"></i> Approve</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *closest only work with sibling* No. `closest` works only on ancestors. **For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.** https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: this works on the first element on the list, and on the first click alone. If i select an `li` in the middle of the list it doesn't work. And once i have clicked on the approve, and the `li` has been hidden, on the next click, it doesn't work.

Comment: ID must be unique but in your case id is same. So it's happen.Give class name on approve button . And it's work.

Comment: so generate unique id not same.It's rule violation.